# Email issue (send hyperlink in email body) android

Tags: android, android-intent, html-email

```
mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(""));

mIntent.setType("text/html");  
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.Google.com/");
mIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+myUri+"\">Link</a>"));
startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Email:"));
```

I tried the above code but at receiver side I can not get Link. it convert into normal text..

Comment: I copied/pasted your code and its working for me...

Comment: Have you checked at receiver side?, OP mentioned that its not showing at receiver end.

Comment: Yes I send an email to my gmail account and then check this trough the Chrome Browser and it was working.

Comment: Can you show me some proof, as me too not getting

Comment: Why do you need a porof ? Believe me, I exactly copied and pasted this and the link is working both on my computer and gmail's app for smartphone.

Comment: @AlexisCartier you should use comment instead of Answer

Answer (score 13):

Try this one..
It is working for me..

```
String link_val = "www.google.com"
String body = "<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + link_val+ "</a>"

intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

Comment: The difference is that if we provide link and its value to the same then it is working else not i.e. `<a href=\"www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>` is working while `<a href=\"www.example.com\">my custom text</a>` isn't.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour, I'm guessing <a href=\"www.example.com\">www.example.com</a> is working because gmail auto converts text that starts http or www into a link.

Comment: This works prefectly fine only when we put www . but is there any way that can i put  some other text to link_val ex-: this

Comment: @Mr.G no, Android not supporting this way.

Comment: But this has worked on previous gmail versions . Not works with the update version . Lets say for marshmellow

Answer (score 1):

CapDroid's answer does not look like it solves the problem, as per scottytab's comment.

Try;

```
yourIntent.setType("text/html");
yourIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

If that doesn't work try adding;

```
yourIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

References; [fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)), [EXTRA_HTML_TEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT)

Comment: yourIntent.setType("text/html") leads to "No application to perform this action" on Marshmallow and yourIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body)); doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

If you make the EXTRA_TEXT a full html document by enclosing the source text in `<html><body>` and `<\body><\html>` it will work properly with GMail, that is, you can have a proper description for the link.

Unfortunately, it won't work with all email apps. For example it does not work with the Samsung email app on my Galaxy S3. My conclusion is that you cannot safely do this, which is very annoying.

Comment: should be `</body></html>` at the end

Comment: I just tried with Android simulator which uses Gmail and it is not working.