# How to include a hyperlink in Intent.ACTION_SEND EXTRA_TEXT

Tags: html, android-intent

This question has been asked [here. Please read this to understand the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004097/email-issue-send-hyperlink-in-email-body-android)

But if you read down to the bottom you will see that the accepted answer only appeared to work because of the behavior of Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have come to the conclusion that this cannot be safely done. The same EXTRA_TEXT when sent using the GMail app worked, but did not work using the Samsung mail app nor a bluetooth send from my Samsung Galaxy S3.