# Deep link not appearing as a clickable link in an email on Android

Tags: android, html, deep-linking

I have tried two ways to send a deep link to an android phone by email:

```html
<a href="mycoolapp://somepath">Open my app</a>
```

and

```html
mycoolapp://somepath
```

Neither of these produces a clickable link when the email is viewed on an Android phone. The first (which was the way recommended by the ionic plugin I use) just shows the raw html.

Is there a way to make the deep link clickable in the same way that a url is?

Comment: Have you checked this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004097/email-issue-send-hyperlink-in-email-body-android ?

If you have a different situation, please let me know.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Some email clients do not like abnormal protocol and they remove links from `href` attribute. When you inspect, you can see that `a` element is still there, but `href` is missing.

The workaround for this is to use normal url and redirect from there like proxy eg.

`https://example.com?url=mycoolapp://somepath`