# How to insert a deep link on html email

Tags: html, android-intent, mobile, html-email, deep-linking

I'm sending an HTML email with some informations for the user, however I want to make a deep link for an app.

I tried to make something like this:

`<p><a href="intent://tecnonutri://diary/#Intent;">Abrir Meu Diário</a></p>`

But when I send the email there is no link on the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email issue (send hyperlink in email body) android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004097/email-issue-send-hyperlink-in-email-body-android)

Answer (score 0):

Felipe Augusto, may be you can try like this it'll work

```
<form action="your://linkhere" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="value" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I have an app called "tecnonutri", it'll be like this ```<form action="tecnonutri://" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="value" />
</form>``` ?

Comment: ya it should work,   or you can try this way (yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx) too

Comment: Forms don't generally work on emails. EDIT: Looks like this was answered a while ago.