# How to set hyperlink for text and send via email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, hyperlink

I have below text and want to send as hyperlink via email.

String id1String = "XES";

String id2String = "ZX02";

String appLink = "myapp://myhost/myaction?id1=" + id1String + "&id2=" + id2String;

I have used below code but not working.

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(appLink));

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i("Finished send email...", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Use spannableString

Comment: @Praveen : If you can give me example it would be great as i'm doing this code first time.

Comment: Also you can try this in xml <string name="share_string"><![CDATA[via <a href="http://google.com">Hyperlink name</a>]]></string>

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004097/email-issue-send-hyperlink-in-email-body-android

Comment: @Joe : I have tried that option but not working.

Comment: Did you try your linkhtml in this format, `String message = "<html>" +
"<head><title>"+subject+"</title></head>" +
"<body>" +
"Click <a href=\"" + returnAddress + "\">here</a> to activate your free subscription." +
"</body>" +
"</html>";`

Comment: @Joe : Not working. Please try my link and test
myapp://myhost/myaction?id1=" + id1String + "&id2=" + id2String

Answer (score 0):

You can use html text as body in email intent.

```
 public void mailIntent() {
    String linkUrl = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    String body = "<a href=\"" + linkUrl + "\">" + linkUrl+ "</a>";
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "fdads");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i("Finished send email...", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, Please try with below link :
myapp://myhost/myaction?id1=" + id1String + "&id2=" + id2String

Comment: This must be the email app behavior To make url as link. Although i have no idea about it  right now.